# Source for this very well known figure or similar figure for nuclear matter distribution

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, specific-reference

I'm doing some presentation and I would like to use this figure

[image: this figure]

which I saw in multiple presentations and in textbooks. The problem is I never see its reference cited and I would like to find it in better quality. Does anyone know where this comes from?

Or: does anyone has some other figure I could use to illustrate the nuclear matter distribution in the nucleus (yes, I know, here it's charge distribution).

Comment: What textbooks did you find it in?

Comment: That's the thing... It has been some years since I did not use textbooks nor looked at some so I could not tell. And I still have this figure from somewhere, not knowing from where I took it. But I see it sometimes in presentations.

Comment: I tried a reverse search on google but no result...

Comment: The experimental data most likely come from electron scattering. Theory is probably Hartree-Fock. Note that the nuclei are almost all doubly magic.

Comment: Those curves look like ones that I generated in my PhD dissertation. It was published  in PR C in 1971 (Miller , Green).

Comment: Correction My dissertation was published in 1971  but the journal article was published in 1972.

Comment: It is also possible that this figure appeared in a 1976 paper of mine entitled Elastic Electron Scattering Formalism for Relativistic Nuclear Models. In that paper I showed how to convert the matter distributions of my earlier work into charge distributions go comparison with experiment. I am currently away from home. But will try to find the original source when I return.

Comment: @LewisMiller In the PRC of 1972 (link : https://journals.aps.org/prc/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevC.5.241) you indeed have a very similar figure. I thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also found some similar figure in

> K Heyde, Basic Ideas and Concepts in Nuclear Physics (Editor Douglas F Brewer)

Figure 1.9 of second edition is pretty similar. It cites work Phys Rep 148, 249 as the reference for this figure but it does not seem to appear in this paper.

Edit: I finally found the image. It comes from

> Rev.Mod.Phys. 54 (1982) 913-1015 `https://inspirehep.net/literature/169255`

Answer (score 3):

I do not know the reference for the plot you showed but here is a similar one you might like better. [image]

This also shows the charge radius. The reference for this is:https://inspirehep.net/record/823384?ln=en

Comment: This is a nice figure, but it doesn't replace the one the OP exhibits because it doesn't show the explicit comparison between theory and experiment.

Comment: Best I could find. His call...

Comment: Or I should have said OP's call.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The figure you present is very similar to Figure 1 in my paper ["Relativistic Self-Consistent Meson Field Theory of Spherical Nuclei" PRC **5**, 241 (L. D. Miller and A E S Green), 1972](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevC.5.241).  Figure 1 is found on page 248.  It is not an exact reproduction of my figure however.  My figure employs the same stacked data format but lacks  experimental data for Zr-90 as well as both experimental and theoretical data for Ni-58.  My figure also lacks the offsets along the x-axis.  In my figure the dashed curves are just labeled "Theory" as opposed to "Mean Field Theory" and the labels are located in the top right corner rather than the bottom right corner.

As other answers have pointed out, other authors later reproduced my calculations and published similar results.  The figure you have must be from one of those later works.

Comment: Too bad that the paper is paywalled. Are the experimental data also in your paper? Are they from electron scattering?

Comment: @BenCrowell Yes, the experimental data are displayed in the figure in my paper and they are the result of elastic electron scattering.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer: there are similar figures in [Gambhir, Ring, and Thimet, *Annals of Physics* **198**, 132-179 (1990)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(90)90330-Q).  You might start there and look at that paper's citations and at the papers that cite it.

That seems like the type of figure that would appear in Ring and Shuck's [The Nuclear Many-Body Problem](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540212065), but I don't currently have access to that textbook to check.

Comment: I feel this is the kind of answer we typically discourage here. I learned nothing from it; I must click on the links to extract information from it. Don't you think it works much better as a comment?

Comment: I don't *think* so. The question is "source for [...] similar figures" and my first link, as I wrote, contains several very similar figures --- just with one nucleus per plot, rather than the clever stacked presentation in the question. Given the level of agreement between the model and the data, I think that late 80s/early 90s is the right part of the literature to search for the original. And Peter Ring is all over the nuclear structure literature from that era --- if he didn't produce that figure, he cited it somewhere.